# Does the notation $x \mapsto(x+2 \mathbb{Z}, x+3 \mathbb{Z})$ refers to $x \mapsto(x+2 k, x+3 k) , k \in Z$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation

I found a notation in a problem and which was not used in the lecture and I didn't cross before:

It asks to show that the application is a ring homomorphism:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\varphi: \mathbb{Z} & \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z} \\
& x \quad \mapsto(x+2 \mathbb{Z}, x+3 \mathbb{Z})
\end{aligned}
$$

I looked up wikipedia pages on "ring" and modular arithmetic but I don't find use of such notation, I am guessing it is some convention of notation and it refers to $x \mapsto(x+2 k, x+3 k) , k \in Z$ am I correct?

Comment: Do you know what an element of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ looks like?

Comment: an element of $\{\overline{0}, \overline{1}, \overline{2}, \cdots, \overline{n}\}$ ?

Comment: For $a \in \Bbb Z$, $a+n\Bbb Z$ is just a different notation for $\overline{a}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of a somewhat broader bit of notation for quotient rings such as $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. In particular, $2\mathbb Z$ refers literally to the set of even numbers $\{2k : k\in \mathbb Z\}$ and $1+2\mathbb Z$ refers to the set of odd numbers $\{1+2k:k\in \mathbb Z\}$. It's fairly common to see arithmetic done on sets this way, where we use a set like $\mathbb Z$ in an expression to stand in for "the set of all possible evaluations of this expression" - for instance, one sometimes sees equations even like $4\mathbb Z + 6 \mathbb Z = 2\mathbb Z$, which is literally true of sets. This is related to various operations on *ideals* in ring theory (although one should be really careful that it is far less common to use this notation with sets being multiplied together - for the good reason that multiplication in a quotient ring is not necessarily multiplication of each element of a coset).

The point of the notation is that the ring $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ consists of the additive cosets of $2\mathbb Z$ - it is a ring whose two elements are "the set of even numbers" and "the set of odd numbers" and the usual projection that reduces mod $2$ happens to be given by
$$f:\mathbb Z\rightarrow\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$$
$$f(x)=x+2\mathbb Z.$$
It's common to represent the elements of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ by the numerals $\{0,1\}$ - or sometimes with various ornaments like $\bar 0$ and $\bar 1$ which tend to be defined as "the set of even numbers $2\mathbb Z$" or "the set of odd numbers $1+2\mathbb Z$", but the literal meaning of a quotient involves these cosets - which are given by shifting the set $2\mathbb Z$ by addition. Note that the notation of cosets is rather flexible, since it lets you write $0+2\mathbb Z$ and $2+2\mathbb Z$ and $4+2\mathbb Z$ and so on as equally valid (and **equal**) elements of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. Mod $3$ works similarly.

So the notation
$$g(x)=(x+2\mathbb Z,x+3\mathbb Z)$$
is really sending each $x\in \mathbb Z$ to a pair consisting of a coset of $2\mathbb Z$ (in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$) and a coset of $3\mathbb Z$ - as is required by the literal definition of these things. That is, it takes an integer to a pair of sets, the first set being in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, the second in $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

No, your interpretation is not correct.

$x + 2\mathbb{Z}$ is the coset of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ that contains $x$. So for example if you write the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ as $\{0, 1, \ldots, n-1\}$ then in this example the image of $8$ is the pair $(0,2)$.